# I have prefixed a text no. in an Excel column, but after the all number formatting is changed, how do I get the numbers along with the added text?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

Example:

Originally it was  (as text format ) 23456789. After adding text it read as RNE1.2012E+11 but if I format using format cells only numbers are restored.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the time to improve your question. See our [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) instructions.

Answer (score 1):

This method only stores the number, as the 'RNE' is the Custom formatting and the number is just a standard numeric value. It only works for prefixed numeric values, not text or other formatted cell values.

The added prefix text will only stay if the Custom formatting is enabled in Format Cells.

Comment: Dear yasin txs for reply to the 1st question i could able to solve the 2nd problem by a simple method :- create 2 coloums type your reqd text , and add 2 coulums with the simple formula =b1&c1 , stike enter & drag the rows .